# console.log this.props show undefined but renders correctly on react redux page

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a very strange error in react redux project. I have payload

```js
const req = {  
  setcolor:false,
  hours:2,
  searchterm:'',
  dropdownvalue:1,
  dropdownvaluetwo:1,
  rooms:[  
    'private-messages',
    'project2',
    'project3',
    'project4',
    'project5',
    'project6',
    'project7',
    'project8',
    'project9'
  ],
  chatrooms:[  
    {  
      key:1,
      color:false,
      name:'private-messages'
    },
    {  
      key:2,
      color:false,
      name:'project2'
    },
    {  
      key:3,
      color:false,
      name:'project3'
    },
    {  
      key:4,
      color: false,
      name:'project 4'
    },
    {  
      key:5,
      color: false,
      name:'project 5'
    },
    {  
      key:6,
      color: false,
      name:'project 6'
    },
    {  
      key:7,
      color: false,
      name:'project 7'
    },
    {  
      key:8,
      color: false,
      name:'project 8'
    },
    {  
      key:9,
      color: false,
      name:'project 9'
    }
  ],
  projectchat:[  
    {  
      projectname:'private-messages',
      chatmessages:[  
        {  
          username: 'ankur',
          message: 'whatsup'
        },
        {  
          username: 'ankur',
          message: 'kya hal hai'
        }
      ]
    },
    {  
      projectname:'project2',
      chatmessages:[  
        {
          username: 'ankur',
          message: 'whatsup'
        },
        {  
          username: 'ankur',
          message: 'kya hal hai'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Now, on front end , If i use

```
<div>
  {this.props.projectlist.hours}
</div>
```

I see correct value on page which is  2. But, if i do

```
<div>
{this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name}
</div>
```

It throws me an error as property undefined.

Now, if i do

```
<div>
{console.log("this.props",this.props.projectlist}
{this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name}
</div>
```

This console log shows me undefined. This is really strange error. Either, I am overlooking something very simple or this quirk is related to redux internal working. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Is this payload coming from an API call? I guess the `payload` is not available in first render. Therefore it shows error. You need to put a condition there like `{this.props.projectlist.chatrooms ?
 this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name : ""}`

Comment: @Prakashsharma Or just `{this.props.projectlist.chatrooms && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name}`

Comment: this is not async request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are getting this `req` object from an endpoint, or from some kind of async. If this is the case, then there is a point in time when `this.props.projectlist` is not yet your request object, therefor `this.props.projectlist.chatrooms` will be undefined, which mean there is no index 0 for chatrooms and so on.

You can solve this by making sure your values are in place before you try and use them.

Something along the lines of

```
if (this.props.projectlist && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0] && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name ) {
// run my code
}
```

I find this solution to be longwinded and personally because I use `lodash` in my javascript projects you can just use lodashs' `get`, like so ( if you want to use lodash, of course). Alternatively you could try and make a little function to run a null coalesce for you.

```
 if (_.get(this.props.projectlist, 'chatrooms[0].name', false ) {
// run my code
}
```

(the third arg here is a a value if any of the nodes are not found/undefined. I've set it to false to pass over this if statement, because our data is not there)

The above examples are for JS, **If you want to keep it all inside the jsx you can use the && trick as well**, something like :

```
{this.props.projectlist && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0] && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name &&
 <div>
   {this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name}
 </div>
}
```

**TL:DR** - your props probably aren't there the very first render when the console.log is running.

Comment: this is not async request

Comment: when i use your code, i got this https://screencast.com/t/24MedjzaI

code is 
{lr}<br/>

   {if (this.props.projectlist && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0] && this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name ) {
                          return <div><p>i am here</p>
{this.props.projectlist.chatrooms[0].name}


                          }}


                       {kr}

Comment: @AnkurSharma as I mentioned in my response, if you want to use this inside jsx, use the && trick. If statements do not work inside jsx.

Comment: https://screencast.com/t/gnJNEfVl4Z

I used it , but still i am getting error . @anmajmajma

Comment: @AnkurSharma please read what I wrote **you cannot use if statements in jsx** , you have to use the && trick as I have demonstrated above, like `{yourValidations && <div> your code </div> }` . You keep linking code that is invalid JSX syntax. Look at react's docs for example - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html